# there exist analytic function with $f(\frac{i^n}{n})=-1/n^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist analytic function with $f(\frac{i^n}{n})=\frac{-1}{n^2} \forall n\ge 2$, well I guess Yes, beacuse $g(z)=f(z)+z^2$ has zero set $\{-\frac{i}{n}: n \text{ odd}\}$ which has limit point zero, hence $f(z)=-z^2$ Is my answer is correct?

Comment: If you plug $z = i^n/n $ into $f(z) = -z^2$, you don't always get $-{1 \over n^2}$. Therefore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plug in $i^3/3$, you'll see that $f(z)=-z^2$ fails to satisfy the desired property.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is basically correct but your answer is not.  You have deduced that the only possible solution is $-z^2$, but even this fails, so there is no solution.